# Top/bottom black stripes for non wide screens in DirectX

Tags: winapi, directx

I need to put black stripes up and down for full screen rendering when wide resolutions are not supported.

Example: for 1280x1024 resolution I need to render in 1280x720 and put black stripes to fill the screen up to 1280x1024

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do believe that the thing you need can be achieved with a viewport change, check out http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb206341(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 0):

make your backbuffer the size of the screen resolution (eg: 1280x1024), then render every to a texture (of 1280x720) and render that texture to the center of the screen, after all post-processing. this is probably not the most efficient solution, but its a starting point.

A better solution is actually making your system work on 4:3 resolutions, users would probably enjoy that more than a letterboxed view, and it should be to difficult.